# OS X remote sharing without needing to install an app on the client

Tags: macos, remote-control, screen-sharing

My clients have OS X (as I do) but have trouble installing the GoToMyPC app, and indeed, any apps — TeamViewer requires that the client install their app, too.

Is there a remote management/screen sharing program that does not require the computer being helped to install anything at all?

Answer (score 1):

In Yosemite (not sure about other versions) there is a Screen Sharing function built into Messages, if you get the iMessage addresses of your team you'll be able to screen share with them. This can be done manually with the built-in Screen Share app, but isn't nearly as easy and convenient as just clicking on them then hitting Share Screen in a Messages conversation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://www.showmypc.com and just execute it with a code. You must have Java installed though. OR you can use VNC or Remote Desktop.

Comment: Installing Java is harder than installing an app